# xsl:template / xsl:apply-templates remove child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I need a hand with sub nodes transformation.
For some reason, `<extra>` tag loses it child nodes after the XSLT application.

The original XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item id="1.0.14797349">
    <metadata>
        <general>
            <somemeta>some data</somemeta>
        </general>
    </metadata>
    <content>
        <grouphead>
            <headline><p>Alabama vs. Clemson: Keys to winning national championship game</p></headline>
        </grouphead>
        <text>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <extra><title>Lorem ipsum</title><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></extra>
            <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</p>
            <crosshead>Some title</crosshead>
            <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus</p>
        </text>
    </content>
</item>
```

The XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/item">

        <ARTICLE type="article" visibility="hidden">
            <SOMEMETA><xsl:value-of select="//metadata/general/somemeta" /></SOMEMETA>
            <TITRE><xsl:value-of select="//content/grouphead/headline" /></TITRE>
            <TEXTE>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </TEXTE>
        </ARTICLE>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="crosshead" priority="1">
        <h4 class="title">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </h4>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content/text/node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected XML result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ARTICLE type="article" visibility="hidden">
    <SOMEMETA>some data</SOMEMETA>
    <TITRE>Alabama vs. Clemson: Keys to winning national championship game</TITRE>
    <TEXTE>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <extra><title>Lorem ipsum</title><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></extra>
        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</p>
        <h4 class="title">Some title</h4>
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus</p>
    </TEXTE>
</ARTICLE>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/item">
    <ARTICLE type="article" visibility="hidden">
        <SOMEMETA>
            <xsl:value-of select="metadata/general/somemeta" />
        </SOMEMETA>
        <TITRE>
            <xsl:value-of select="content/grouphead/headline" />
        </TITRE>
         <TEXTE>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="content/text/*"/>
        </TEXTE>
    </ARTICLE>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="crosshead">
    <h4 class="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </h4>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```